# How can I modify this regex to match all three cases?

Tags: python, regex

I want to test if a method appears in a header file. These are the three cases I have:

```
void aMethod(params ...)
//void aMethod(params
// void aMethod(params
  ^ can have any number of spaces here
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
re.search("(?<!\/\/)\s*void aMethod",buffer)
```

Buf this will only match the first case, and the second. How could I tweak it to have it match the third too?

EDIT:sorry, but I didn't express myself correctly. I only want to match if not within a comment. So sorry.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the negative look behind `(?<!\/\/)` it implies that you want not to match on comment lines, but that would mean it should only match the first case.

Comment: In my test the regex matches the first and the third case, like expected. Geo, are you sure, it matches the first and second case?

Comment: Oh damn! I didn't express myself clearly. I only wanted to match if not within a comment. I will ask another question.

Comment: If you want to ignore comments, I suggest to "preprocess" your file to ignore/remove comments as a first step.  If you process the file line by line, just check if it is a comment line before searching for your method.  See also pygments' clexer: http://pygments.org/docs/api/#lexers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, after your edit, Geo, it is this:

```
^(?<!\/\/)\s*void aMethod
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to find all appearances for 'void aMethod(params' then you can use the following:

```
a = """void aMethod(params ...)
//void aMethod(params
// void aMethod(params
  ^ can have any number of spaces here"""
from re import findall
findall(r'\bvoid aMethod\b', a)
```

OR:

```
findall(r'(?:\/\/)?[ ]*void aMethod', a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp.

```
(\/\/)?\s*void aMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

For the three options:  `(?:\/\/)?\s*void aMethod`