# How can I find a method name not within a comment?

Tags: python, regex

I asked [this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436837/how-can-i-modify-this-regex-to-match-all-three-cases) but I didn't express myself correctly. If I have these three cases:

```
void aMethod(params ...)
//void aMethod(params
// void aMethod(params
  ^ can have any number of spaces here
```

How could I tweak my regex to match only if the string is not found in a comment? This is my regex:

```
re.search("(?<!\/\/)\s*void aMethod",buffer)
```

Would this catch everything:

```
(?<!\/\/)(?<!\s)+void onMouseReleased
```

Comment: Are those the only three cases? What about: `/*foo void aMethod(params) bar*/` (multi-line comment) and `"foo void aMethod(params) bar"` (string literal)

Comment: Doesn't Python have a tokenizer?

Comment: @Bart, multiline will not appear.

Comment: @Geo, and string literals that might possibly contain text that look like method calls?

Comment: Plz, tell us more about your problem. There is a good chance, it'll be insane to solve with regexps. BTW, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygccxml, http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/.

Comment: I'm looking in a lot of source files to see if 2 methods exist. They do, in most files. I'm trying to find the ones in which they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the stuff for your examples :

```
re.search("^(?!\/\/)\s*void aMethod",line)
```

Comment: I'm just curious, would a negative lookbehind solution be possible?

Comment: @Geo, no, since the look behind must have a fixed width. So you can't put `\s*` or `\s+` inside a look-behind.

Comment: Yes, I know about the fixed width. But couldn't the look-behinds be repeated with a +, like a look-behind for space?

Comment: You should perhaps allow for extraneous whitespace elsewhere too. And searching for start-of-line and then immediately negative lookahead is the same as using match and just not including `//` in the regexp: `re.match("\s*void\s+aMethod\s*\(\s*params")`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular need to use regex? If not you can also try to use the following:

```
a = """void aMethod(params ...)
//void aMethod(params
// void aMethod(params
  ^ can have any number of spaces here"""

for line in a.split('\n'):
    if not line.strip().startswith("//") and "void aMethod(params" in line:
        print line
```

Edited as per lazyr comment

Comment: This will exclude `void aMethod(params //`, which should be included, and include `var = "asdf aMethod asdf"`, which should be excluded. Do `if not line.strip().startswith("//") and "void aMethod(params" in line` instead. Keep in mind this only works if there are no extraneous whitespace here and there, like this: `void  aMethod( params`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore comments, I suggest to "preprocess" your file to ignore/remove comments as a first step. see: [Python snippet to remove C and C++ comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241327/python-snippet-to-remove-c-and-c-comments)